# Single word for "self-mastery and fortitude in the face of boorish behavior"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a word that is defined thusly:

> the self-mastery and fortitude with which a person conducts himself in the face of life's vicissitudes and the boorish behavior of others.

Comment: I'd start with rectitude and look at synonyms and the definitions of those synonyms.

Comment: Same with _hardy_, _stalwart_, and _stout_.

Comment: Wait, is the OP really Alex Trebek? ;^]

Comment: @Dave4183 - Why did you ask this question, given that you likely already knew the answer?

Comment: **What is "dignity"?** for 1000.

Answer (score 4):

This apparently comes from an article called *A Nation of Cowards* by Jeffrey R. Snyder, originally published in the Fall, '93 issue of *The Public Interest*.  It is archived at [the website for National Affairs, Inc.](http://www.nationalaffairs.com/public_interest/detail/a-nation-of-cowards) (its parent company, I think).

The full quote is:

> "Dignity" used to refer to the self-mastery and fortitude with which a person conducted himself in the face of life's vicissitudes and the boorish behavior of others.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I might also add the word "grace". "He acted with grace and dignity in the face of tribulation "

Comment: This is a very apt quote, and expresses what the OP is after. However, you should provide the source and a link (if possible) to the source. I did a quick search, hoping to be able to provide these for you, but could not find the exact quote in the time I had to devote to it

Comment: @ab2 I doubt there is a third party to cite. I think the quotation marks are being used not to indicate a borrowing but to indicate spoken language.